# Bash if statement [: missing `]' error

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

I am having trouble with bash. I am trying to put a command in an `if` statement and then compare it to a string.

This works perfectly.

```
echo $(ipcs | grep Shared | awk '{print $2}')
```

When I put it in an `if` statement I get some problems.

```
$ if [ "$(ipcs | grep Shared | awk '{print $2}')" -eq "Shared"]; then
  echo expression evaluated as true;
else
  echo expression evaluated as false;
fi
bash: [: missing `]'
expression evaluated as false

$ if [ "$(ipcs | grep Shared | awk '{print $2}')" = "Shared"]; then
  echo expression evaluated as true;
else
  echo expression evaluated as false;
fi
bash: [: missing `]'
expression evaluated as false

$ if [ "$(ipcs | grep Shared | awk '{print $2}')" == "Shared"]; then
  echo expression evaluated as true;
else
  echo expression evaluated as false;
fi
bash: [: missing `]'
expression evaluated as false
```

I tried `==`, `=`, and `-eq` because I wasn't sure which one to use.

Comment: For those wondering: these are not multi-line statements!

Comment: If you just want to check whether the string `Shared` appears in the command output you might want to consider using the exit status of grep directly e.g. `ipcs | { if grep -q "Shared"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi }` or `ipcs | grep -q "Shared" && echo "true" || echo "false"` - see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48536/65304 for example

Answer (score 92):

Your `missing ]'` error is because you need a space at the inbetween `"Shared"` and `]`, so the line should be `if [ "$(ipcs | grep Shared | awk '{print $2}')" == "Shared" ]; then`.

Comment: I had the same problem.  This solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, why do we need a space?