# Grep string then delete word and do next statement

Tags: bash, grep

I want to create bash shell script which can 
 - find string in file
 - then delete word
 - then restart service

I have tried this code

Restart.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -q 'RestartServiceApache' /srv/www/config_apa
if [ $result -eq 1 ];
        then
                sed '/RestartServiceApache/d' "/srv/www/config_apa"
                /etc/init.d/httpd reload
fi
```

and my config_apa

```
Hello my name is nutnud.

#RestartServiceApache
```

This is all just a test file.

and the Error is

```
./Restart.sh: line 3: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

I tried a lot of script and it doesn't work there is always an error like cannot grep or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Bourne Shell, to see the exit code status you can use:

```
$?
```

It looks like grep should give a 0 status if it matched a line and a 1 status if it did not match (http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html), so you want to match for exit code 0.

So you could do this:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  grep -q 'RestartServiceApache' /srv/www/config_apa
  if [ $? -eq 0 ];
       then
            sed '/RestartServiceApache/d' "/srv/www/config_apa"
            /etc/init.d/httpd reload
  fi
```

However, an easier way can be found in the following answer:

[Can grep return true/false or are there alternative methods](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48535/can-grep-return-true-false-or-are-there-alternative-methods)

> ```
>  if grep -q PATTERN file.txt; then
>      echo found 
>  else
>      echo not found 
>  fi
> ```

Replace the "echo found" portion with your code to remove the line and restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

With new **GNU sed** it can be done in one line

```
sed -i '/RestartServiceApache/{e\/etc/init.d/httpd reload
                               d}' /srv/www/config_apa
```