# Shell script exits early for unclear reasons

Tags: shell-script, exit, borgbackup

I'm using the following script to backup, using [Borg Backup](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/). But I'm running into an odd problem

Part of the script below does not execute. The script follows, then the output

SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                  

set -ex
set -o pipefail
export SERVER="myserver"
CLEVEL=zlib,9
. /home/faheem/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh

#borg init -e none faheem@$SERVER:/mnt/backup-test                                                                                                         
borg create -c 30 --compression $CLEVEL --stats faheem@ramnode:/mnt/backup-test::`hostname`-`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H.%M`  /home/faheem/test-borg                   
{ borg check faheem@$SERVER:/mnt/backup-test 2>&1 1>&3 | tr '\r' '\n' | grep -Ev "^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$" 1>&2; } 3>&1
mapfile -t testarchives < <(borg list --short faheem@$SERVER:/mnt/backup-test)
borg extract -n "faheem@$SERVER:/mnt/backup-test"::"${testarchives[-1]}"
```

OUTPUT:

```
+ set -o pipefail
+ export SERVER=ramnode
+ SERVER=ramnode
+ CLEVEL=zlib,9
+ . /home/faheem/.keychain/orwell-sh
++ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-F7Uzg6CeQoTY/agent.5660
++ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
++ SSH_AGENT_PID=5661
++ export SSH_AGENT_PID
++ hostname
++ date +%Y-%m-%d:%H.%M
+ borg create -c 30 --compression zlib,9 --stats faheem@ramnode:/mnt/backup-test::orwell-2016-09-16:05.04 /home/faheem/test-borg
+ borg check faheem@ramnode:/mnt/backup-test
+ tr '\r' '\n'
+ grep -Ev '^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$'
```

So the last two lines don't execute. But if I comment out the earlier lines, those two lines execute. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

UPDATE: If I take out grep (i.e. replace)

```
{ borg check faheem@$SERVER:/mnt/backup-test 2>&1 1>&3 | tr '\r' '\n' | grep -Ev "^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$" 1>&2; } 3>&1
```

with

```
{ borg check faheem@$SERVER:/mnt/backup-test 2>&1 1>&3 | tr '\r' '\n' 1>&2; } 3>&1
```

I get

```
+ set -o pipefail
+ export SERVER=ramnode
+ SERVER=ramnode
+ CLEVEL=zlib,9
+ . /home/faheem/.keychain/orwell-sh
++ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-F7Uzg6CeQoTY/agent.5660
++ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
++ SSH_AGENT_PID=5661
++ export SSH_AGENT_PID
++ hostname
++ date +%Y-%m-%d:%H.%M
+ borg create -c 30 --compression zlib,9 --stats faheem@ramnode:/mnt/backup-test::orwell-2016-09-17:03.18 /home/faheem/test-borg
+ borg check faheem@ramnode:/mnt/backup-test
+ tr '\r' '\n'
Remote: Checking segments 0.0%
Remote:                         
+ mapfile -t testarchives
++ borg list --short faheem@ramnode:/mnt/backup-test
+ borg extract -n faheem@ramnode:/mnt/backup-test::orwell-2016-09-17:03.18
```

Does the `Remote:` line correspond to `grep` failing to match the pattern and returning non-zero?

Here are a couple of relevant questions:

[Can grep return true/false or are there alternative methods](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48535/can-grep-return-true-false-or-are-there-alternative-methods)

and

[Avoid grep returning error when input doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550484/avoid-grep-returning-error-when-input-doesnt-match)

The latter question appears to be a similar situation, if not the same.

Answer (score 3):

The `set -e` means that if grep returns non-zero (ie the pattern is not matched) then that, combined with `pipefail` means that the pipe fails and causes the script to abort.

So either

- remove `set -e`
- remove `pipefail`
- Add an `|| true` in the `grep` segment to ensure that always returns zero

Comment: The truthfulness of a pipeline without `pipefail` is the exit status of the last command. Therefore, removing pipefail doesn't help him here if the `grep` is not matching.

Comment: Right, but if other components of the pipeline are returning non-zero then it might.

Comment: Hi, Stephen. The third option looks like it would be the best. I don't need `grep` to succeed. So, if it doesn't match a pattern, that's considered an error? Weird. What would the syntax look like, exactly? The syntax of that particular command is already quite convoluted.

Comment: I would try replacing `grep -Ev "^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$" 1>&2` with `{grep -Ev "^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$" 1>&2 || true;}` but it might need some tuning.

Comment: Or you could use `sed`, since `grep` is *designed* to have its exit status set according to whether the pattern is matched or not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Wildcard. What would the syntax look like in this case? Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: I tried `{ borg check faheem@$SERVER:/mnt/backup-test 2>&1 1>&3 | tr '\r' '\n' | { grep -Ev "^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$" || true } 1>&2; } 3>&1` but this gives: "line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file". My shell knowledge is pretty sketchy, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is designed to set an exit status according to whether or not a particular pattern is found, and in some cases is even used *only* for this purpose and any output is suppressed.  (That's the purpose of the `-q` switch to `grep`.)

`sed` is the "Stream EDitor" and is designed to filter a stream of text, converting it in some way (usually line by line) as it passes through.

Although there is a great deal of overlap between these two utilities, they do each have a specific purpose.  In this case you are evidently not interested in whether or not the pattern is found, you simply want to filter the text stream before passing it along.  That is a proper use case for `sed`, not for `grep`.

---

```
sed -E '/^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$/d' delme.txt
```

This is the exact equivalent of:

```
grep -Ev '^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$' delme.txt
```

**...except** that the `grep` command will give an error exit status if there are no lines besides those matching the pattern, and `sed` will not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On the face of it, `sed` does indeed look like a better choice here. Does the `$/d` simply remove a line that matches the regex on the left; i.e. `^Remote:\s*(Checking segments.*)?$`? I'm not familiar with `sed`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, yes; lines which match the regex (`/.../`) have the `d`elete command applied to them.  Other lines have `sed`'s default action applied, which is to print the line (unless suppressed with `-n`).

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the clarification, Wildcard.

Comment: @FaheemMitha you're welcome.  The best free tutorial for learning `sed` is [the Grymoire page](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).  I encourage you to read up on it--I've found `sed` indispensable as a sysadmin.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, Wildcard. That looks like basically a book.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. Does `sed` only operate on standard output?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, you mean standard input?  No, it can work on files (any number of files).

Comment: Hi Wildcard. I think I meant standard output, but maybe I mean standard input. The reason I'm asking is that I had to do gyrations with file descriptors (see above) so `grep` could act on standard output (or input).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45505/discussion-between-wildcard-and-faheem-mitha).